# Windows custom keyboard shortcut has delay of 3 seconds

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, windows-11, start-menu

I created a shortcut in `C:\Users\guill\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Ubuntu` and when I press the combination of keys then there is a delay of 3 seconds before the app starts.

I want to reduce this delay to 200 ms or so.

I know this delay is caused by Windows trying to figure out if any opened app can make use of this shortcut before doing the action that I've set. Can this be changed in the registry or somewhere with a dll editing tool or anything?

I'm considering reinstalling linux as my main OS at this point.
Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you click the shortcut with a mouse?

Comment: There is no delay when clicking by mouse.